# change current date to new selected date for retrieving firebase data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to display data from firebase using dates. But I only know how to display data for the current date. I would like to change the dates so I can display data from firebase with different dates. The current code I have is only displaying the data on a recyclerView from 8-9-2020. I would like to get the data from the previous day which is 7-9-2020.
[image]

```
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String currentDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child("food").child(currentDate);


        buttonCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCalendar();

            }
        });
        Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
        String date = incomingIntent.getStringExtra("date");
        theDate.setText(date);
```

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                month = month +1;
                String date = String.format("%02d-%02d-%d", dayOfMonth, month, year);

                Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, Breakfast.class);
                intent.putExtra("date", date);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

What I'm trying to do is it will display the current date data, then when I select a new date from the calendar, it will retrieve data of the newly selected date.
I would like to somehow update the **.child(currentDate)** to **.child(date)** in which the date contains the newly selected date.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you're opening a calendar in the new activity I can suggest if you want to use android `DatePickerDialog` to get a date in the same activity.

And if you want to get a date back from a particular activity you can use a `startActivityForResult(yourIntent,request_code);` and get result and data in

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And after getting a successful result you can use the below method to get your firebase data.

```
private void getFirebaseData(String date){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child("food").child(date);
    // rest is your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out simple way to do it:

```
setDate();
String date = setDate();
if (date == null || date.equals("")){
            date = currentDate;    
        }
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child("food").child(date);
```

made a method for setting the new date:

```
public String setDate(){
        Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
        String date = incomingIntent.getStringExtra("date");
        theDate.setText(date);
        return date;
    }
```